# How to block all software shutdown requests in android?

Tags: debian, shell, systemd, android, shutdown

I rooted my android-based TV box and installed Debian Jessie on it. I have some crucial services like web servers and Homebridge on it that I want to run uninterruptedly on Debian, and I really hope I can try to prevent my TV box remote from shutting it down. Is there any way to block that action?

I consider myself quite familiar with Debian based distros, but I do not know how android works. So far, what I've tried is: replacing `/sbin/shutdown`, `/sbin/halt` (both of which are from Debian), and replacing `/system/bin/reboot`. None of which seems to be working.

Just as a side note; the Android version is 4.4.

Comment: Debian Jessie uses systemd, so the daemon that reads the remote is probably calling `systemctl shutdown` or similar. You definitely don't want to replace `systemctl` without replacing the entire init system though

Comment: Is it possible that the remote is just triggering a circuit that cuts power?  If so, you may not be able to do what  you want with a software configuration.

Comment: DopeGhoti I've considered this but I don't think this is the case, since I can see services and processes shutting down from serial if I connect it to my computer.